# Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Db_Dbl_Table' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am trying to write a upgrade script but unfortunately I am getting an error that says

> Fatal error: Class **Varien_Db_Dbl_Table** not found in
>   **mysql4-upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php** on line 7.

**Here is my code**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('abhi_gallery/gallery'))
    ->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null,
        array(
            'identity' => true,
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
            'primary'  => true,
        ), 'Value id')
    ->addColumn('cms_page_id', Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null,
        array(
            'nullable' => false,
        ), 'Cms page id')
    ->addColumn('position', Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null,
        array(
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => true,
        ), 'Position')
    ->addColumn('file', Varien_Db_Dbl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 255,
        array(
            'nullable' => false,
        ), 'File Name')
    ->addColumn('label', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 255,
        array(
            'nullable' => true,
        ), 'Label')
    ->addColumn('is_disabled', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN, null,
        array(
            'nullable' => true,
        ), 'Is Disabled');

$installer->getConnection()->createTable( $table );

$installer->getConnection()->addForeignKey(
    $installer->getFkName(
        'abhi_gallery/gallery',
        'cms_page_id',
        'cms/page',
        'page_id'
    ),
    $installer->getTable('abhi_gallery/gallery'),
    'cms_page_id',
    $installer->getTable('cms/page'),
    'page_id'
);
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Comment: you don't need that Varien_Db_Ddl_Table because  you already assiging $table once again to connection->newTable()

Comment: add your `config.xml ` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your update script for typos ... error says

```
Varien_Db_Dbl_Table
```

that really does not exist, it should be

```
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table
```

<sup>(`_Ddl_` instead of `_Dbl_`)</sup>

Comment: I spent 5 -  7 min to this question and I am not able to find diff between `b` and `d` , great

Comment: Happens. Sometimes the problem is in front of the screen :P